# Modifying field in abstract class using reflection

Tags: java, testing, reflection, junit

I'm trying to modify a private field in an abstract class with reflection.
I already was successful with a regular class, but in this case my code doesn't work:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass{
    private String str;
    public void func1(){
       //...
    }
}

public MyClass extends AbstractClass{}

// JUnit

MyClass tester = new MyClass();
Class<?> secretClass = tester.getClass();
Field fields[] = secretClass.getDeclaredFields();

@Before
public void setup() {
    for (Field field : fields) {
        try {
            field.setAccessible(true);
            if (field.getName().equals("str")) {
                field.set(tester, "Hello");
                System.out.println(field.getName());
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException | IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

// some testing
@Test
public void testFunc1() {
    //tester.func1();
}
```

It can't access the String `str` in `AbstractClass`. No output is shown here. If I copy `str` to `MyClass`, it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The javadoc for [`Class#getDeclaredFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredFields--) states

> Returns an array of Field objects reflecting all the fields declared
>   by the class or interface represented by this Class object. This
>   includes public, protected, default (package) access, and private
>   fields, **but excludes inherited fields**.

So the field `str` is not included in the returned array. You'll have to recursively (or iteratively) traverse parent classes and their fields. If the fields are `public`, you can use [`getFields()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getFields--).

Comment: The fields in the abstract class are private. Is there any chance to access and modify those fields?  
How to test an abstract class anyway?

Comment: @user1170330 As I've stated, access the parent class of the concrete subclass and use its `getDeclaredFields()` method. Testing and abstract class depends on the class itself. Testing concrete subclasses will possibly cover testing their parent classes.

Comment: How can I get the abstract class from the subclass? Is there something like `this.getAbstractClass()` that I can call from the subclass?

Comment: @user1170330 If you look at the javadoc that I've linked in my answer, you'll find a [`getSuperclass()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getSuperclass--) method. Call that until you get `null`, retrieving (and modifying) the fields as you go along.